# Applications exercises of linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I am interested in applications problems of Linear Algebra.
If somebody can recommend me an interesting book, or papers about, I will appreciate this.
Thanks.
(I need this for a course of Linear Algebra for Engineering where I am the lecturer).

Comment: You should state your background in linear algebra otherwise it's hard to give you a sensible answer.

Comment: It would also help if you could get a little more specific. On the linear algebra end, you could specify some linear algebra topic. On the application end, you could identify some general field of study/science/technology. Otherwise, just about any application problem can be rephrased as a linear algebra application.

Answer (score 1):

The standard course on applied linear algebra is the textbook of the same name by Ben Noble and James W.Daniel. Try and get the most recent edition. There is also a wealth of applications,all very instructively discussed by a master, in Gilbert Strang's *Linear Algebra With Applications*.Both of these books are probably the best general sources for the applications of vector space theory to the empirical and social sciences,as well as other areas of mathematics. After these, one moves on to more specialized topics, such as numerical linear algebra.

Comment: BTW,whoever keeps downvoting all my posts-feel free since the moderators seem to have little interest in doing anything about it and I don't know who you are.

Comment: There you go-have at it.BTW-anyone who upvotes my posts,do you mind they're downvoting them out of spite? Just curious.

Comment: As we have told before, there are no signs of systematic downvoting against you as detected by the software—interest has nothing to do with this. We simply cannot prevent other users from voting your answers down, if only for the reason that we do not know who the downvoters are. When there is a significant;y suspicious voting pattern for of against a user, we *do* get informed by the software, and we generally act immediately.

Comment: Thank you Mathemagician1234 !

Comment: @alpha No problem-good luck!

Comment: @Mariano All right,I'll stop bitching about it now. I just hate when people get their kicks at my expense-I have enough REAL problems without having to worry about THAT childishness. Sorry to be such a pain about it.